# Is there a way to sum the elements of a sub-hash in a NDS using two while loops?

Tags: ruby, multidimensional-array, nested

I am trying to target the element "worldwide_gross", add up these up for each movie belonging to each movie director, then return a hash with the name of movie director as a key and sum of "worldwide_gross" for all their movies as a value.

```
result = Hash.new(0)
i = 0 #which movie director's hash we're on
while i < nds.length do
  j = 0 # which key in each director's hash
  while j < nds[i][:movies].length do
    total += nds[i][:movies][j][:worldwide_gross].to_i
    j += 1 
  end
  i += 1 
  result[name] = total
end 
return result
```

Here is the data structure:

```
nds = [{
  :name => "Stephen Spielberg",
  :movies => [{
    :title => "Jaws",
    :studio => "Universal",
    :worldwide_gross => 260000000,
    :release_year => 1975
  }, {
    :title => "Close Encounters of the Third Kind",
    :studio => "Columbia",
    :worldwide_gross => 135189114,
    :release_year => 1977
  }, {
    :title => "Raiders of the Lost Ark",
    :studio => "Paramount",
    :worldwide_gross => 248159971,
    :release_year => 1981
  }, {
    :title => "E.T. the Extra-terrestrial",
    :studio => "Universal",
    :worldwide_gross => 435110554,
    :release_year => 1982
  }, {
    :title => "Schindler's List",
    :studio => "Universal",
    :worldwide_gross => 96898818,
    :release_year => 1993
  }, {
    :title => "Lincoln",
    :studio => "Buena Vista",
    :worldwide_gross => 182207973,
    :release_year => 2012
  }]
}, {
  :name => "Russo Brothers",
  :movies => [{
    :title => "Avengers Endgame",
    :studio => "Buena Vista",
    :worldwide_gross => 858371337,
    :release_year => 2019
  }, {
    :title => "Avengers Infinity War",
    :studio => "Buena Vista",
    :worldwide_gross => 678815482,
    :release_year => 2018
  }, {
    :title => "Captain America Civil War",
    :studio => "Buena Vista",
    :worldwide_gross => 408084349,
    :release_year => 2016
  }, {
    :title => "Captain America The Winter Soldier",
    :studio => "Buena Vista",
    :worldwide_gross => 259766572,
    :release_year => 2014
  }, {
    :title => "You, Me and Dupree",
    :studio => "Universal",
    :worldwide_gross => 75628110,
    :release_year => 2006
  }, {
    :title => "Welcome to Collinwood",
    :studio => "Warner Brothers",
    :worldwide_gross => 336620,
    :release_year => 2002
  }]
}, {
  :name => "James Cameron",
  :movies => [{
    :title => "Avatar",
    :studio => "Fox",
    :worldwide_gross => 760507625,
    :release_year => 2009
  }, {
    :title => "Titanic",
    :studio => "Paramout",
    :worldwide_gross => 659363944,
    :release_year => 1997
  }, {
    :title => "Titanic",
    :studio => "Paramout",
    :worldwide_gross => 659363944,
    :release_year => 1997
  }, {
    :title => "Terminator 2 Judgment Day",
    :studio => "TriStar",
    :worldwide_gross => 205881154,
    :release_year => 1991
  }, {
    :title => "True Lies",
    :studio => "Fox",
    :worldwide_gross => 146282411,
    :release_year => 1994
  }, {
    :title => "Aliens",
    :studio => "Fox",
    :worldwide_gross => 85160248,
    :release_year => 1986
  }, {
    :title => "The Abyss",
    :studio => "Fox",
    :worldwide_gross => 54461047,
    :release_year => 1989
  }]
}, {
  :name => "Spike Lee",
  :movies => [{
    :title => "Inside Man",
    :studio => "Universal",
    :worldwide_gross => 88513495,
    :release_year => 2006
  }, {
    :title => "BlacKkKlansman",
    :studio => "Focus",
    :worldwide_gross => 49275340,
    :release_year => 2018
  }, {
    :title => "Malcolm X",
    :studio => "Warner Brothers",
    :worldwide_gross => 48169910,
    :release_year => 1992
  }, {
    :title => "The Original Kings of Comedy",
    :studio => "Paramount",
    :worldwide_gross => 38182790,
    :release_year => 2000
  }, {
    :title => "Jungle Fever",
    :studio => "Universal",
    :worldwide_gross => 32482682,
    :release_year => 1991
  }]
}, {
  :name => "Wachowski Siblings",
  :movies => [{
    :title => "The Matrix Reloaded",
    :studio => "Warner Brothers",
    :worldwide_gross => 281576461,
    :release_year => 2003
  }, {
    :title => "The Matrix",
    :studio => "Warner Brothers",
    :worldwide_gross => 171479930,
    :release_year => 1999
  }, {
    :title => "The Matrix Revolutions",
    :studio => "Warner Brothers",
    :worldwide_gross => 139313948,
    :release_year => 2003
  }, {
    :title => "Jupiter Ascending",
    :studio => "Warner Brothers",
    :worldwide_gross => 139313948,
    :release_year => 2015
  }, {
    :title => "Speed Racer",
    :studio => "Warner Brothers",
    :worldwide_gross => 47387723,
    :release_year => 2008
  }, {
    :title => "Cloud Atlas",
    :studio => "Warner Brothers",
    :worldwide_gross => 27108272,
    :release_year => 2012
  }]
}, {
  :name => "Robert Zemeckis",
  :movies => [{
    :title => "Forrest Gump",
    :studio => "Paramount",
    :worldwide_gross => 330455270,
    :release_year => 1994
  }, {
    :title => "Cast Away",
    :studio => "Fox",
    :worldwide_gross => 233632142,
    :release_year => 2000
  }, {
    :title => "Back to the Future",
    :studio => "Universal",
    :worldwide_gross => 210609762,
    :release_year => 1985
  }, {
    :title => "The Polar Express",
    :studio => "Warner Brothers",
    :worldwide_gross => 187224490,
    :release_year => 2004
  }, {
    :title => "Who Framed Roger Rabbit",
    :studio => "Buena Vista",
    :worldwide_gross => 156452370,
    :release_year => 1988
  }, {
    :title => "What Lies Beneath",
    :studio => "Dreamworks",
    :worldwide_gross => 155464351,
    :release_year => 2000
  }]
}, {
  :name => "Quentin Tarantino",
  :movies => [{
    :title => "Django Unchained",
    :studio => "Weinstein",
    :worldwide_gross => 162805434,
    :release_year => 2012
  }, {
    :title => "Once Upon a Time in Hollywood",
    :studio => "Sony",
    :worldwide_gross => 135156125,
    :release_year => 2019
  }, {
    :title => "Inglourious Basterds",
    :studio => "Weinstein",
    :worldwide_gross => 120540719,
    :release_year => 2009
  }, {
    :title => "Pulp Fiction",
    :studio => "Miramax",
    :worldwide_gross => 107928762,
    :release_year => 1994
  }, {
    :title => "Kill Bill Vol. 1",
    :studio => "Miramax",
    :worldwide_gross => 70099045,
    :release_year => 2003
  }, {
    :title => "Kill Bill Vol. 1",
    :studio => "Miramax",
    :worldwide_gross => 66208183,
    :release_year => 2004
  }]
}, {
  :name => "Martin Scorsese",
  :movies => [{
    :title => "The Departed",
    :studio => "Warner Brothers",
    :worldwide_gross => 132384315,
    :release_year => 2006
  }, {
    :title => "Shutter Island",
    :studio => "Paramous",
    :worldwide_gross => 128012934,
    :release_year => 2010
  }, {
    :title => "The Wolf of Wall Street",
    :studio => "Paramount",
    :worldwide_gross => 116900694,
    :release_year => 2013
  }, {
    :title => "The Aviator",
    :studio => "Miramax",
    :worldwide_gross => 102610330,
    :release_year => 2004
  }, {
    :title => "Cape Fear",
    :studio => "Universal",
    :worldwide_gross => 79091969,
    :release_year => 1991
  }, {
    :title => "Gangs of New York",
    :studio => "Miramax",
    :worldwide_gross => 77812000,
    :release_year => 2002
  }]
}, {
  :name => "Francis Ford Coppola",
  :movies => [{
    :title => "The Godfather",
    :studio => "Paramount",
    :worldwide_gross => 134966411,
    :release_year => 1972
  }, {
    :title => "Apocalypse Now",
    :studio => "MGM",
    :worldwide_gross => 83471511,
    :release_year => 1979
  }, {
    :title => "Apocalypse Now Redux",
    :studio => "Miramax",
    :worldwide_gross => 83471511,
    :release_year => 2001
  }, {
    :title => "Bram Stoker's Dracula",
    :studio => "Columbia",
    :worldwide_gross => 82522790,
    :release_year => 1992
  }, {
    :title => "The Godfather Part III",
    :studio => "Paramount",
    :worldwide_gross => 66666062,
    :release_year => 1990
  }, {
    :title => "Jack",
    :studio => "Buena Vista",
    :worldwide_gross => 58620973,
    :release_year => 1996
  }]
}]
```

The expected hash is

```
{
  "Stephen Spielberg"=>1357566430,
  "Russo Brothers"=>2281002470,
  "James Cameron"=>2571020373,
  "Spike Lee"=>256624217,
  "Wachowski Siblings"=>806180282,
  "Robert Zemeckis"=>1273838385,
  "Quentin Tarantino"=>662738268,
  "Martin Scorsese"=>636812242,
  "Francis Ford Coppola"=>509719258
}
```

My output is not returning, because it says nil cannot be added to the total.

Comment: See "[mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)". Reduce data to the bare minimum necessary to duplicate the problem you're seeing. Anything beyond that wastes our time when we're debugging the problem, and can even drive potential help away.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Enumerable#to_h](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-to_h)

```rb
# to_h example
# (1..3).to_h { |num| [num, num + 10] } #=> {1=>11, 2=>12, 3=>13}

pp nds.to_h do |director| 
  [director[:name], director[:movies].sum { |movie| movie[:worldwide_gross] }]
end
```

output

```rb
{
  "Stephen Spielberg"=>1357566430,
  "Russo Brothers"=>2281002470,
  "James Cameron"=>2571020373,
  "Spike Lee"=>256624217,
  "Wachowski Siblings"=>806180282,
  "Robert Zemeckis"=>1273838385,
  "Quentin Tarantino"=>662738268,
  "Martin Scorsese"=>636812242,
  "Francis Ford Coppola"=>509719258
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get values like this:

```
nds.each_with_object({}) do |nds_hash, directors|
  directors[nds_hash[:name]] = nds_hash[:movies].sum{ |movies| movies[:worldwide_gross] }
end

#=> {
      "Stephen Spielberg" => 1357566430,
      "Russo Brothers" => 2281002470,
      "James Cameron" => 2571020373,
      "Spike Lee" => 256624217,
      "Wachowski Siblings" => 806180282,
      "Robert Zemeckis" => 1273838385,
      "Quentin Tarantino" => 662738268,
      "Martin Scorsese" => 636812242,
      "Francis Ford Coppola" => 509719258
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code isn't working because you never created/initialized `total` and `total += ...` is just trying to increase the value of a non existent variable. Same goes for the `name` variable, you did not create it but you're using it's value. You should replace:

```
result[name] = total
```

with something like:

```
result[nds[i][:name]] = total
```

Which makes the code produce the results you asked for:

```
result = Hash.new(0)
i = 0 #which movie director's hash we're on
while i < nds.length do
  j = 0 # which key in each director's hash
  total = 0
  while j < nds[i][:movies].length do
    total += nds[i][:movies][j][:worldwide_gross].to_i
    j += 1 
  end
  result[nds[i][:name]] = total
  i += 1 
end 
puts result
#=> {"Stephen Spielberg"=>1357566430, "Russo Brothers"=>2281002470, "James Cameron"=>2571020373, "Spike Lee"=>256624217, "Wachowski Siblings"=>806180282, "Robert Zemeckis"=>1273838385, "Quentin Tarantino"=>662738268, "Martin Scorsese"=>636812242, "Francis Ford Coppola"=>509719258}
```

Or you can do something like this:

```
your_array.map.with_object({}) do |director, hash|
  hash[director[:name]] = director[:movies].sum {|movie| movie[:worldwide_gross]}
end

 #=> {"Stephen Spielberg"=>1357566430, "Russo Brothers"=>2281002470, "James Cameron"=>2571020373, "Spike Lee"=>256624217, "Wachowski Siblings"=>806180282, "Robert Zemeckis"=>1273838385, "Quentin Tarantino"=>662738268, "Martin Scorsese"=>636812242, "Francis Ford Coppola"=>509719258}
```